# Create Listview programmatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am new to ASP.net and I would like to programmatically create a dynamic Listview component. 
I found examples on how to do that for Gridview and Datatable but not Listview. Is it possible?
Does anyone know of a good tutorial?

Comment: Please post the example link of `Gridview and Datatable`, so that we know exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
private void CreateMyListView()
 {
  // Create a new ListView control.
  ListView listView1 = new ListView();
  listView1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(10,10), new Size(300,200));
  // Set the view to show details.
  listView1.View = View.Details;
  // Allow the user to edit item text.
  listView1.LabelEdit = true;
  // Allow the user to rearrange columns.
  listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
  // Display check boxes.
  listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
  // Select the item and subitems when selection is made.
  listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
  // Display grid lines.
  listView1.GridLines = true;
  // Sort the items in the list in ascending order.
  listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

  //Creat columns:
  ColumnHeader column1 = new ColumnHeader();
  column1.Text = "Customer ID";
  column1.Width = 159;
  column1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

  ColumnHeader column2 = new ColumnHeader();
  column2.Text = "Customer name";
  column2.Width = 202;
  column2.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

  //Add columns to the ListView:
  listView1.Columns.Add(column1);
  listView1.Columns.Add(column2); 


  // Add the ListView to the control collection.
  this.Controls.Add(listView1);
 }
```

Or take a look at that [Example](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/23287-Programmatically-Create-List-View.aspx)

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.Drawing
 Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class listview
Inherits Form

Friend WithEvents btnCreate As Button

Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    btnCreate = New Button
    btnCreate.Text = "Create"
    btnCreate.Location = New Point(10, 10)

    Me.Controls.Add(btnCreate)
    Text = "Countries Statistics"
    Size = New Size(450, 245)
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
End Sub

Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click

    Dim lvwCountries As ListView = New ListView
    lvwCountries.Location = New Point(10, 40)
    lvwCountries.Width = 420
    lvwCountries.Height = 160

    Controls.Add(lvwCountries)

End Sub

Public Shared Sub Main()
    Application.Run(New Exercise)
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

*Basic idea of how to approach this task. The key concepts are the same ones a `GridView` would require.*

1) You need somewhere on the page to put the `ListView` - a **container** for it.

2) This container needs to **run at the server**, so your C# code (which the server evaluates) can add the `ListView` to it. Two example containers you could use: a `Panel` and a standard `div` tag with the `runat=server` property.

3) Choose **when** the code to create the ListView will be **called** and **how**. I recommend you define it as a **method** and call it from whatever **event** you want e.g.:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call your method here so the ListView is created
    CreateListView();
}

private void CreateListView()
{
    // Code to create ListView here
}
```

4) Use below code in above method to create the `ListView` and add it to the container like so:

```
var myListView = new ListView();
containerName.Controls.Add(myListView);
```

You will need to add to the `ListView`'s **properties** for it to be aesthetically pleasing, on top of the obvious databinding.

The code found on [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a9295967-7233-44ed-8091-f754909a7a8a/) has some example properties you will most likely want to use.